# Specify max length attribute to match varchar(max)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model like so:

```
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
public string Title { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
public string Slug { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

As you can see for the `Body`, I set a limit of 100, but in the database this column is `varchar(max)`. What can I put for length to match the column's `varchar(max)` ?

Comment: `varchar(max)` holds up to 2GB of data, I believe, so you could use `int.MaxValue`.  @teovankot makes a good point about the -3, so I suppose my comment should be:  `int.MaxValue - 2`.

Comment: [StringLength(int.MaxValue)]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have two options:

(1) Use `int.MaxLength` as `maximumLength` argument of the `StringLengthAttribute` constructor:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(int.MaxValue, MinimumLength = 3)]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

(2) Decorate the property additionally with `MaxLengthAttribute` w/o parameters (the value of the `StringLengthAttribute` will be ignored):

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
[MaxLength]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

Comment: The Solution will only work with the varchar datatype (2^31-1 characters) (as requested), but when you are using the Nvarchar datatype you will get an error, because int.maxvalue (2^31-1 characters)  is bigger then Nvarchar(max) (2^30-1 characters), that will not match.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DataAnnotations.Schema`. I am using the following for `varchar(max)`

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
[MaxLength]
```

Answer (score 1):

`VARCHAR(MAX)` is `2^31-3` chracters in unicode [check here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).

So you can just put this number. But don't know why you need this =) :

```
[StringLength(2147483645, MinimumLength = 3)]
```

Comment: @frc oh, then int.MaxValue  is the best ;)